# Hover states on SVG elements

Tags: svg, hover

Linked SVG elements don't seem to behave like linked HTML elements. If you link a circle, or a path (including text rendered as paths) you have to hold your mouse *directly* above the content in order to activate the hover state. Holding your mouse in the white space between the shapes does not trigger a hover state.

Example CodePen of hovering on different SVG element types:
http://codepen.io/bmarshall/pen/VjgJpb

Interestingly, hovering on real `<text>` elements behaves a little more like HTML and the hover state activates even in the white space!

Is this just "The Way It Is" in SVG? Why is text handled differently than other shapes? Can one change this behaviour if desired? How?

Comment: Whitespace is fundamenally just text.

Comment: In what sense do you mean?

Comment: a space is no different to a letter of the alphabet as far as text is concerned, modulo xml:space compression of course.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't understand what you're trying to say here. I've got end-of-the-day fuzzy brain atm.

Comment: The alphabet in English consists of the letters abcde...xyz. A space or carriage return character in SVG is treated the same as one of those i.e. the same as the letter a except you can't see a space and you can see an a

Comment: Ohh I think I understand your point here. I didn't actually mean whitespace as in "the spaces between letters in a line of text" (the kind you get when you hit your spacebar). I meant it more in the design sense as in "the unused areas around elements in a design". You are correct, spaces in text do technically constitute characters. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121101/discussion-between-robert-longson-and-brad-marshall).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change that svg background on hover you can use a wrapper for that svg with sgv size and you check when they hover in the wrapper you change the svg background

Comment: Hmm... I'm more interested in affecting hover states on the _inside_ of the SVG graphic. It's a good suggestion however - I tried grouping my paths in a <g> element and wrapping my link around that but the hover behaviour remains the same. I will try wrapping the item with a transparent rect and linking that but even if that works, it seems like a lot of work if there are many links involved.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that...

a) Yes, this is just the way linked SVG elements behave. SVG is not HTML and links work a little differently in the two. Nature of the beast.

b) Text saved in a true SVG `<text>` element behaves differently when linked than text saved as paths because real text and paths are fundamentally different concepts/technologies. Linked paths, be they `<circle>`, `<rect>`, or text saved in a `path` element have similar hover behaviours because they're essentially all path objects under the hood (or at least can be thought of as such). Text however, is truly laid out by a text engine using fonts, baselines, glyphs and such and is rendered via different means than regular plain old paths. I won't embarrass myself by trying to explain more deeply than that but basically, they act differently when linked because they are conceptually distinct and each gets rendered in it's own way.

c) Not much can be done about changing the hover behaviour of a linked element on the inside of an SVG. It's possible that there is some way for a linked SVG element to mimic the hover behaviour of another via some hack or workaround (your mileage may vary with wrapper elements) but this is kind of just how links work in SVG so it's best to just be aware of the difference and choose your element types wisely if you ever plan to link them.